# How to change projection to lat long from eastings and northings, QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I'm using QGIS and I'm trying to get the coordinate system into lat/long instead of eastings/northings. I think I'm choosing the correct coordinate system, but my "Extent" is listed in eastings/northings. I'm new to QGIS so I don't know what I should do next. Is there a re-project tool that I'm missing? I've attached an image for reference:

[image]

Comment: This is one of the very common mistakes, asserting rather than projecting, redefine back to the original coordinate reference system, load as a layer in QGIS then right click, select *save as* then change the output CRS to *as specified* and choose EPSG 4269, this will change the vector coordinates to geographic and set the CRS you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recompute the extent by going from the `information` tab to the `Source` tab.

Then click the `Update Extents` button.

If that doesn't work, go back to the source layer, and in the layer list you can right-click it then go down to `Export > Save Features As`.

In the `CRS` portion of that window you can change it to output the new layer to EPSG:4269 - NAD83.

Comment: Hmm... I did both of these things and the Extent never updated. It still says its EPSG:4269 - NAD83 as before. It's very strange and stubborn. Is there a way I could do this with Python or something else?

Comment: @densify open an empty, new QGIS project and load the layer there. Then follow the second set of instructions I've shared here.